# Counter that increments on scroll into Viewport

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, counter

I'm trying to create a useEffect in React that starts when the number appears on the screen and it stops once it gets to a certain value (once per website loading).

I found some answers here that use getBoundingClientRect and refs but they are very vague and specific to the other contributors questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example for you which creates a counter that starts counting when it becomes visible on the screen, and stops when it reaches a specified value (targetCount). The `IntersectionObserver` API is used to detect when the element is visible on the screen. The `countRef` is used to refer to the DOM element that needs to be observed. The counter increments every second (`1000 milliseconds`) until it reaches the target count.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const CounterComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const countRef = useRef(null);
  const targetCount = 10; 

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
          setCount((prevCount) => {
            if (prevCount < targetCount) {
              return prevCount + 1;
            } else {
              clearInterval(interval);
              return prevCount;
            }
          });
        }, 1000); 
      }
    }, { threshold: 1 });

    if (countRef.current) {
      observer.observe(countRef.current);
    }

    return () => {
      if (countRef.current) {
        observer.unobserve(countRef.current);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={countRef}>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CounterComponent;
```

Comment: Thank you. that's exactly it! I added more numbers like this: https://prnt.sc/sqegqoip7lCE   . It probably isn't the best solution but it'll have to do. Could you please explain this code to me in more detail, or provide a reference that I can use? I looked up IntersectionObserver on MDN docs but it's very confusing